# CondaDependencyError: multiple python records found in prefix

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, python-3.6

Can't install requirements using Anaconda:

**PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4**

**Project interpreter in settings**
[image: Project interpreter in settings]

**Requirements installation failure**
[image: Requirements installation failure]

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed all python and Anaconda installations and reinstall only Anaconda solved the issue. I had multiple installations for both Python and Anaconda...